# Why is toString() throwing NullPointerException in Android SDK (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am building a simple calculator in android, i already made it work with simple x operator x form but i am trying to make it work with more than 2 tokens, and while using parenthesis.

I am using an add-on Library to do the interpretation.
**EDIT: doccumentation for Interpreter Class: http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/bsh/Interpreter.html**

**I tried using this code in java standalone and it worked:**

```
public double evaluate(String express) {
    double value = 0;
    String answer = null;

    String base = "result = ";
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();

    try {
        interpreter.eval(base + express); 
        answer = interpreter.get("result").toString();//this line
        value = Double.parseDouble(answer);
    } catch (EvalError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**But when i used it in android, the toString() method is throwing a nullpointerexception, why is that?
why in android specifically?**

Comment: Simply put the object you are calling toString() on is null...

Comment: I know that, but why this problem is happening in android only?

Comment: What does Interpreter do? what's the code?

Comment: I don't think Interpreter is available in android as I search for it in android library does not find it there. Just for information, android takes some of java part, not the full of java part.

Comment: It's an addon library (Jar), you can find it here, http://www.beanshell.org/download.html
the second link

Comment: check this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Please edit your code to include your call to evaluate. Standing alone, this code is a method declaration with no invocation. The result will depend upon how you call evaluate. Can you include the smallest possible set of working software ?

Answer (score 8):

> But when I used it in Android, the `toString()` method is throwing a nullpointerexception

It is not. You even don't get into that method.

Because the `interpreter.get()` method returned null. It is like writing:

```
null.toString();
```

That is what happens.

Comment: Haha, I am a fan of this answer.

Comment: Yes i know that, but why did it work for normal standalone java?

Comment: The reason for that might be that the libraries are different, or that your code isn't the same as the code you used in the desktop version.

Comment: aha, the Interpreter.get() returns an Object object obviously, how can i cast it to double?

Comment: You don't have the Interpreter class in Android

Comment: It's an addon library (Jar), you can find it here, beanshell.org/download.html the second link

Comment: check this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: No, sorry, but wen you say that Interpreter.get() returns an Object, you are incorrect. The Interpreter.get() method appears to return null, not an object. null.toString() throws a NullPointerException